# High charts tooltip location issues

Tags: highcharts

I have developed a high chart but having issues with the tooltip location.
    It seems it does not refresh properly. When I take mouse it's either stuck or shows the tool tip for the earlier point where I had put the mouse. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong.

```
Here is a fiddle for you to playaround.
http://jsfiddle.net/Mn6sB/

$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chartContainer',
                type: 'spline'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Pass rate statistics'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Pass count per xxx'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                minTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                    month: '%e. %b',
                    year: '%b'
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'PassCount'
                },
                min: 0
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/> Pass Count: '+ this.y;
                }
            },

            series: [{name: 'dev', data:[[Date.UTC(2013,9,25),12],[Date.UTC(2013,9,24),41],[Date.UTC(2013,9,23),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,22),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,20),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,19),10],[Date.UTC(2013,9,18),22],[Date.UTC(2013,9,17),12],[Date.UTC(2013,9,16),16],[Date.UTC(2013,9,15),11],[Date.UTC(2013,9,14),4],[Date.UTC(2013,9,13),25],[Date.UTC(2013,9,12),11],[Date.UTC(2013,9,11),20],[Date.UTC(2013,9,10),16],[Date.UTC(2013,9,9),7],[Date.UTC(2013,9,7),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,5),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,4),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,3),22],[Date.UTC(2013,9,2),13],[Date.UTC(2013,8,31),7],[Date.UTC(2013,8,30),12],[Date.UTC(2013,8,29),12],[Date.UTC(2013,8,28),5],[Date.UTC(2013,8,27),23],[Date.UTC(2013,8,26),2],]},{name: 'test', data:[[Date.UTC(2013,9,25),24],[Date.UTC(2013,9,24),4],[Date.UTC(2013,9,21),16],[Date.UTC(2013,9,20),41],[Date.UTC(2013,9,19),42],[Date.UTC(2013,9,18),42],[Date.UTC(2013,9,17),4],[Date.UTC(2013,9,16),3],[Date.UTC(2013,9,15),3],[Date.UTC(2013,9,14),3],[Date.UTC(2013,9,13),3],[Date.UTC(2013,9,12),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,11),3],[Date.UTC(2013,9,9),3],[Date.UTC(2013,9,8),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,7),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,6),10],[Date.UTC(2013,9,1),3],[Date.UTC(2013,8,30),1],[Date.UTC(2013,8,29),1],[Date.UTC(2013,8,28),10],]},{name: 'intermediate', data:[[Date.UTC(2013,9,25),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,24),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,23),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,22),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,21),2],[Date.UTC(2013,9,20),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,19),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,18),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,17),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,16),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,15),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,13),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,12),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,11),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,10),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,9),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,8),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,7),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,4),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,3),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,2),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,1),1],[Date.UTC(2013,8,30),1],[Date.UTC(2013,8,29),2],[Date.UTC(2013,8,28),2],[Date.UTC(2013,8,27),2],]},{name: 'main', data:[[Date.UTC(2013,9,25),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,24),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,23),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,22),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,21),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,20),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,19),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,18),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,17),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,16),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,14),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,13),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,12),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,11),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,10),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,9),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,8),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,7),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,6),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,5),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,4),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,3),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,2),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,1),1],[Date.UTC(2013,8,31),1],[Date.UTC(2013,8,30),1],[Date.UTC(2013,8,29),1],[Date.UTC(2013,8,28),2],[Date.UTC(2013,8,27),2],]},{name: 'test_th', data:[[Date.UTC(2013,9,24),4],[Date.UTC(2013,9,1),3],]},{name: 'intermediate_dev', data:[[Date.UTC(2013,9,21),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,13),1],]},{name: 'rel', data:[[Date.UTC(2013,9,15),1],]},{name: 'staging', data:[[Date.UTC(2013,9,6),1],[Date.UTC(2013,8,30),1],]},{name: 'fun', data:[[Date.UTC(2013,9,5),1],[Date.UTC(2013,8,28),2],]},]
        });
    });
```

Comment: Order of data via x is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that all you need to do is sort your data in ascending x value order. This should sort it out.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks that seemed like working for me. But I just realized another problem which you may be able to help. My chart dates goes backward. Means from today it goes backward. But in the chart the legends are going forward which is strange. I am passing month as 9 in the Datew.UTC method still the months is shown as OCT.

Comment: Hi. If my answer is correct, please accept and upvote it so others can tell. Months in javascript start at 0, so 9 is October.